# JS | Умножить инпут при изменении

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="sum" value="1" name="sum" placeholder="Сумма, руб."></input>
<input type="sumUSD" readonly name="sumUSD" placeholder="Вы получите"></input>
```

Есть сумма в рублях, нужно чтобы при изменении sum менялся sumUSD на sum*2 в реальном времени

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то $(selector).keyup(function() {} );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот:

```js
$('input[name="sum"]').on('input', ({currentTarget})=>{
    const summ = +($(currentTarget).val());
    if(summ > 0)$('input[name="sumUSD"]').val(summ * 2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="sum" value="1" name="sum" placeholder="Сумма, руб."></input>
<input type="sumUSD" readonly name="sumUSD" placeholder="Вы получите"></input>
```

Вообще `type="number"` должно быть, а не `type="sum"`